# I cant find an error on Java code (11 lines) - Could you give some idea?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
Packet packet = new Packet(slot, i+1, n+1);
noOfPacketsGenerated++;
if (queues[i][0].size()+queues[i][1].size()+queues[i][2].size()+queues[i]].size()+queues[i][4].size()+queues[i][5].size()+queues[i][6].size()+queues[i][7].size()<QUEUE_SIZE)
    queues[i][n].add(packet);
else {
      bufferFails[i]++;
      if (debug) 
         System.out.println("BUFFER FULL @ node "+(i+1));
     }
```

[errors in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEjvx.png)

I can't find where the errors are?. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: ```queues[i]]``` is present instead of ```queues[i][3]```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image of the error, it looks like you put a duplicate `]` in your code. i.e., you have

```java
queues[i][0].size()+queues[i][1].size()+queues[i][2].size()+queues[i]] // ...
```

where you should have

```java
queues[i][0].size()+queues[i][1].size()+queues[i][2].size()+queues[i] // ...
```

Compiler errors can be cryptic at times, especially if one misplaced character has a cascading effect, but in this case it drew an arrow right to the position where the error occurred.

P.S. that's a really long-winded line of code with lots of room for error. I would recommend either splitting it into a few lines, or making a few temporary values consisting of these separate statements and then putting a shorter, more concise if-statement in your code.